# SQL Query to remove common string

Tags: sql, sql-server

@strA and @strB are two variables

```
@strA = "055367911126753316"
@strB = "00055367"
```

how to find the common part "*055367*" and remove it from string A, using SQL server query without looping?
the result should be "911126753316"

> be noted that always string A begin by the end part of string B

Comment: They have other  common parts also, for example "6", what to do with another common parts?

Comment: always string A begin by the end part of string B

Comment: But String b starts with '000' but in your common part it is 1 '0', Do we need to leave first two 0's of string b?

Comment: The question is not clear, there are so many ways of matching but you have to clear that in which way you want to match ?

Comment: the result in my example should be "911126753316"
because the common part is "055367"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This, works dynamically.

```
declare @StrA Nvarchar(250)='055367911126753316',@StrB Nvarchar(250)='0055367'

select right(@StrA,len(@strA)-PATINDEX('%[^'+@StrB+']%',@strA)+1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use replace in sql server as below:

```
declare @strA varchar(50) = '055367911126753316'
declare @strB varchar(50) = '00055367'

select replace(@strA,right(@strB,len(@strB)-2),'')
```

If it is in different columns in a table you can use as below:

```
create table #yourcolumns ( cola varchar(50), colb varchar(50))

insert into #yourcolumns (cola, colb) values
('055367911126753316', '00055367')

select replace(cola,right(colb,len(colb)-2),'') from #yourcolumns
```

I think we need to go for substring in your case as you are looking for startswith

```
select SUBSTRING(cola,CHARINDEX(LEFT(REVERSE(colb),1),cola)+1,len(cola)) from #yourcolumns
```

Comment: where are you matching the string ?? what if @strB is `055367`

Comment: actually, A and B represent  two columns in a table and A could be '55367911126753316' in this case your function will not help

Comment: what if I have this:
insert into #yourcolumns (cola, colb) values
('055367911126753316', '00055367')
insert into #yourcolumns (cola, colb) values
('55367911126753316', '00055367')

Answer (score 0):

It YES with looping, But it work....

```
create function MyFn (@A nvarchar(max), @B nvarchar(max))
returns  nvarchar(max)
as
begin

    declare  @I int, @L int, @SUB nvarchar(max)

    select @I = 1, @L =  len(@B)
    while @I<@L begin
        set @SUB = substring(@B,@I,@L-@I+1)
        if charindex(@SUB,@A,1) > 0 begin
            set @A = replace(@A, @SUB, '')
            break
        end
    set @I = @I + 1
    end

    return @A
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @strA varchar(50) = '055367911126753316'
DECLARE @strB varchar(50) = '00055367'

SET  @strA=(SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(@strA, PATINDEX('%[^0 ]%', @strA + ' '), LEN(@strA))))
SET  @strB=(SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(@strB, PATINDEX('%[^0 ]%', @strB + ' '), LEN(@strB))))

SELECT @strA String ,@strB StringtoSearch,REVERSE(SUBSTRING(@strA,0,CHARINDEX(RIGHT(@strA,LEN(@strB)),@strA)))ExpectedOutput
```

Output

```
ExpectedOutput
---------------
911126753316
```

Comment: you are searching for last character in strB in strA
in our example is 7, but this number could be repeated. 
your example doesn't work on strA = '0575367911126753316'
 strB= '000575367'

Answer (score 0):

If each string A starts with 000 and each string b just contains one 0 this should retrieve the correct result

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT [StringA], [StringB],REPLACE([StringB], '000', '0') [tbd] 
FROM YourTable)

SELECT REPLACE(YourTable.[StringA], CTE.[tbd], ''), YourTable.[StringA]
FROM YourTable
JOIN CTE ON YourTable.[StringA]= CTE.[StringA]
```